# Gravity Form Field Focus

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, autofocus, gravityforms

I want to to add focus on the first field of my gravity form  my form if is 39 and the first field id is 1 can someone can tell me how can I achieve this and what code I need and where to paste that code, for your information i am using hello elementor theme.

Please help me with code or snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to an HTML field at the top of your form:

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) { jQuery('#input_39_1').focus(); });
</script>
```